# different requirements with yum and rpm for the same package

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm, package-management

I have a yum repo:

```
[sensu-checks-prod]
name=sensu-checks-prod
baseurl=http://our.internal.repo/pulp/repos/Sensu_checks_el6-prod/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Which is composed of gem to RPMs created with fpm

I have edited this package to change the version requirement of sensu-rubygem(rest-client) which was fixed to **=1.8.0** to  **>=1.8.0**

If I download the package from the repo

```
# wget http://our.internal.repo/pulp/repos/Sensu_checks_el6-prod/sensu-rubygem-sensu-plugins-jenkins-1.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

and check with rpm

```
# rpm -qpR sensu-rubygem-sensu-plugins-jenkins-1.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
ruby  
rubygems  
sensu-rubygem(chronic_duration) = 0.10.6
sensu-rubygem(jenkins_api_client) = 1.4.2
sensu-rubygem(rest-client) >= 1.8.0
sensu-rubygem(sensu-plugin) >= 1.2
sensu-rubygem(sensu-plugin) < 2.0
```

Version requirement is OK: sensu-rubygem(rest-client) >= 1.8.0

If I check with yum:

```
# yum deplist sensu-rubygem-sensu-plugins-jenkins
Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror
Recherche de dépendances :
Determining fastest mirrors    
sensu-checks-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                      | 2.1 kB     00:00     
sensu-checks-prod/primary                                                                                                                                                                                              |  17 kB     00:00     
sensu-checks-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                                       64/64  
paquet : sensu-rubygem-sensu-plugins-jenkins.x86_64 1.2.0-1
  dépendance : sensu-rubygem(jenkins_api_client) = 1.4.2
   provider: sensu-rubygem-jenkins_api_client.x86_64 1.4.2-1
  dépendance : sensu-rubygem(rest-client) = 1.8.0
   Dépendance non satisfaite
  dépendance : ruby
   provider: ruby.x86_64 1.8.7.374-4.el6_6
  dépendance : rubygems
   provider: rubygems.noarch 1.3.7-1.el6
   provider: rubygems.noarch 1.3.7-5.el6
  dépendance : sensu-rubygem(sensu-plugin) < 2.0
   provider: sensu-rubygem-sensu-plugin.x86_64 1.4.4-1
   provider: sensu-plugin.x86_64 1.0-1
   provider: sensu-rubygem-sensu-plugin.x86_64 1.4.5-1
  dépendance : sensu-rubygem(chronic_duration) = 0.10.6
   provider: sensu-rubygem-chronic_duration.x86_64 0.10.6-1
  dépendance : sensu-rubygem(sensu-plugin) >= 1.2
   provider: sensu-rubygem-sensu-plugin.x86_64 1.4.4-1
   provider: sensu-plugin.x86_64 1.0-1
   provider: sensu-rubygem-sensu-plugin.x86_64 1.4.5-1
```

It is NOT ok: sensu-rubygem(rest-client) = 1.8.0

yum clean all has been done of course.

Why yum does not reflect the **>=** that rpm shows correctly ??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna guess that yum is detecting the unmodified version of the RPM that doesn't have the '**>**' turned into '**>=**'.  If you do a `yum list` with the `--show duplicates` flag, you can see if there is more than one out there.

If that's what's going on, using repo priorities is probably what you want to do to fix it.  You can also try `--enablerepo`, `--disablerepo`, or setting filters per repo in the repo configs using `exclude` and `includepkgs`.

Priorities is a plugin in older distros, so you might have to install it.

Comment: you were right !
fixed it by purging the duplicates RPMs in pulp, then it worked.